# replace url of Ext.data.store

Tags: javascript, url, extjs, replace

I have `StoreBaseOn` declared, and I want to change the URL of it and then load it, as my code need to do so. How to change the URL?

declared code:

```
StoreBaseOn =  new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: [myurl],
    root: 'rows',
    idProperty: [myID],
    autoLoad: true,
    remoteSort: true,
    baseParams: [myParam],
    fields: ['id', 'age']
});
```

I know how to change param e.g. `StoreBaseOn.setBaseParam('group', the_group);`
But how to just change the URL?

Answer (score 2):

The *url* is setted in the `proxy` of your store so you can use the following function to set it:

```
StoreBaseOn.getProxy().setUrl("YouNewUrl");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ludovic! sadly I use ExtJS3.4 and which does not have `getProxy()` method yet.
However, by your inspiration, I figured out how to do in my case:

```
StoreBaseOn.proxy.setUrl(myNewUrl)
```